# $or within two $elemMatch using positional $ gives The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

Hi all and thank you very much for you help in advance.

We are trying to build a hierarchical tree of users and at some point we need to push an element inside of a double-nested array.
Imagine the following structure:

```
User A (children -> User B and C)
    User B (parent -> User A, children -> User C)
        User C (parent -> User B)
```

At some point we need to push new user as a sibling of User C, so under User B. The structure would be then something like this:

```
User A (children -> User B, C and D)
    User B (parent -> User A, children -> User C and D)
        User C (parent -> User B)
        User D (parent -> User B)
```

The only information we have when updating is the parent where we have to put the new user under, so we know at that point that user B will be the parent of user C.
I am trying to figure out how do it in a single query, but a query with an $or and two $elemMatch won't work and throws the following error

> The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
>   Unexpanded update: accounts.$.children

this is the query I'm trying

```
db.users.update({
    "$or": [{
        "_id": "User B",
        "accounts": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "group": "GROUPID"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "accounts": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "children._id": "USER B",
                "group": "GROUPID"
            }
        }
    }]
}, {
    "$push": {
        "accounts.$.children": [{
            "_id": "USER D",
            "permission": "write"
        }]
    }
}, {
    multi: true
})
```

The datastructure is the following

```
{
    _id: 'USER B',
    accounts: [{
        group: 'GROUP 1',
        parent: 'User X',
        children: [{
            _id: 'User Y',
            permission: 'write'
        }]
    }, {
        group: 'GROUP 2',
        parent: 'User A',
        children: [{
            _id: 'User C',
            permission: 'write'
        }]
    }]
}
```

The point is they can have different accounts belonging to different groups, and I should only update the account that belongs to the group of the same other users (the groupId is known when updating too)

If i try, exactly the same query within only one of the conditions of the $or (any of them) it works as expected, but with both conditions inside the $or at the same time it fails when using the positional operator $

Maybe the only solution is to make it in two queries, but i wanted to know if it is possible in one, and if not why not. Thank you all very much.

Eric.

Comment: When you use `$or` over an array then you can "potentially" match more than one element. In projection, the positional operator would just select the "first" match in the array ( not the first condition, the first element that matches any condition ). However, as an "update" the positional operator cannot handle this. You cannot potentially match more than one element "directly" in an update. You can "project and loop", but you cannot just update directly with a condition like that.

Comment: Also, you are matching on `"accounts"` array elements, but trying to use the position on the `"entities"` array. That makes litte sense unless your arrays are perfectly asligned for matching elements. Even if that were true, then it would be better to have a single array with all the combined data instead.

Comment: Thank you Blakes. About the **entities**, that was my fault when writing the question, I always was trying to match and to $push into "accounts".

About the $or, I'm not sure if I completely get it, you mean that I can't use the positional operator when I can potentially match more than one element in my query? However, if I use the same exact query with only one condition in the $or (any of both conditions) it works as expected. Also when the $elemMatch matches more than one document, it updates them all. Moreover I know for sure that the first condition in the $or is excludes the second. Thx

Comment: I actually gave you the little piece of code to try and the "hint" that this is not a problem for "projection". Assume this is a document `{ "a": ["B","C"]  }` if you run this condition ( `$in` is a shorter syntax of `$or` ) `{ "a": { "$in": ["C","A"] } }`. Then you cannot "update", resulting in the same error. But if you did this "projection": `{ "a": { "$in": ["C","B"] } },{ "a.$": 1 }` then you would see that `"B"` is the matched element "projected" in the array since it comes first in the document array. You cannot `.update()` but you **can** loop query results and "update".

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to get it. I guess the problem is that I should need two positional operators since the $or also gives a positional operator. So what I can't do, is to use an $elemMatch inside an $or and then use the positional operator for updating. I guess the only way is to do the loop or to divide the query into two.

Thank you very much Blakes, I appreciate your help